# How many people will receive pens under the condition?

Tags: combinatorics

There are $N$ kinds of pens. There are two groups with $M$ person each. You will give the pens to $2M$ person under following conditions(Assume that there are enough pens of each kind):

1. A person cannot receive more than one pen of a same kind.
2. No two person receive same set of pens. If A received {pen 1, pen 2}, no other person receives the same set of pens that A received.
3. For any two person in different groups(for instance, A is in group #1 and B is in group #2), there is a pen that both of them received.

For what values of $M$, in terms of $N$, holds the condition?

From condition #1 and #2, there are $2^N$ different sets of pens(including empty set), so $M \le 2^{N-1}$. Also, it seems that condition 3 lowers the upper bound, and that is where I am stuck. Any ideas for applying condition 3?

Comment: A bipartite graph, but the idea is not formed to an end. Maybe that is we invert every pen set in the first group, there are no {intersecting {{sets of pens} from different groups}}.

Comment: Give everyone pen1, then #3 is satisfied, and start over with just #1 and #2?